# Handling image from within a Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm working on a multi-platform Xamarin project, and in this project, for both iOs and android, I have to download an image, store it on the device and display it with rounded corner.

Saying that, I figured out it would be nice if the downloading /storing part was handle by the Portable Class Library (.Net 4.5) (that's the easy part) and if, before storing, after having fetch my image data as a byte[], i could somehow, inside the PCL, apply the roundRect filter directly to it so that the image data that I'll store will be the one of a image with rounded corner already.
This way, the platform specific code would be just to display an image!

Any thought?

// EDIT :
So to be more specific and show some code :

```
    public async void DownloadAsync (string url)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var respmessage = await client.GetAsync (url);

        var imageByteArray = await respmessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync ();


        imageByteArray = RoundedCornerPNGRepresentation(imageByteArray) ;

        CachePicture (imageByteArray, url);

    }

    byte[] RoundedCornerPNGRepresentation (byte[] imageByteArray)
    {
        // would love to apply a roundedCorner filter to imageByteArray here
    }
```

Comment: If you're only going to be using the images within your app, I'd recommend that you'd rather go with a rounded-corner control, and then make a platform-specific implementation of that instead.